# SQL: Get the column value corresponding to maximum column value

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following table

MyTable

```
Id | S_Id |  T_Id |
1  | 1    |  abc  |
2  | 2    |  abc  |
3  | 3    |  abc  |
4  | 4    |  abc  |
5  | 1    |  xyz  |
6  | 2    |  xyz  |
7  | 3    |  xyz  |
```

I have another table AnotherTable

```
  P_Id | Name |  Id |
    1  | pqr  |  4  |
    2  | stu  |  4  |
    3  | mvc  |  4  |
    4  | yxf  |  3  |
```

I will have T_Id as input e.g: abc. I want a query to select the Id of the row with maximum S_id i.e. 4 and join with the AnotherTable and result is:

```
Id | S_Id |  T_Id |  P_Id | Name | 
4  | 4    |  abc  |  1    | pqr  | 
4  | 4    |  abc  |  2    | stu  |  
4  | 4    |  abc  |  3    | mvc  |
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use `rank()` window function if you are on 11g or before

```
select id
  from (
   select id, rank() over (partition by T_Id order by S_Id desc) as rn
     from myTable
    where T_Id = 'abc') t
where t.rn = 1;
```

on 12c you can use `fetch`

```
select id
  from myTable
 where T_Id = 'abc'
order by S_Id desc
fetch first 1 row;
```

Use Join on your new requirement

```
select t.Id, t.S_Id, t.T_Id, t1.P_Id, t1.Name
  from (
   select id, S_id, t_id rank() over (partition by T_Id order by S_Id desc) as rn
     from myTable
    where T_Id = 'abc') t join AnotherTable t1 on t.id = t1.P_id
where t.rn = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. But is there any other option other than rank. As I want it to run on every database whenever required.

Comment: @SonamDaultani Every Oracle Database? I think Rank() works from 8i onwards

Comment: Yes I meant all oracle versions. I checked it works with all versions above 8i. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: The results of `rank()` vs `fetch first` may be different if there is a tie for maximum `S_Id` (if `S_Id` may have duplicates - otherwise it's not an issue). If duplicates are possible and you really only want one row, you may use `row_number()` instead of `rank()` (for example for a scalar subquery).

Comment: @vercelli My requirement is changed. Can you look into it.